# How to proceed with flaky specs after successful bisect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Using Rails 5 and Rspec 3.7 I have a fairly simple test that is currently flapping (sometimes passing sometimes failing). Through the debugging I've done so far it seems that values i'm saving to my test database are not persisting between tests, but I can not figure out why this is the case.

Here is the test suite with comments on the flapping test (the rest consistently pass)

```
describe ResourceCenterController, type: :controller do
  before(:each) do
    @platform_instance = FactoryBot.create(:platform_instance)
    @domain = FactoryBot.create(:domain, platform_instance: @platform_instance)
    @user = FactoryBot.create(:user, platform_instance: @platform_instance, first_name: "O'flaggan")
  end

  context 'when user IS signed in' do
    before(:each) do
      login_user(@user)
    end

    context 'when user in ONE community' do
      before(:each) do
        @user.communities = [@platform_instance.communities.first]
        @user.save!
      end

      describe '#index' do
        before(:each) do
          @rc = FactoryBot.create(:resource_center, platform_instance: @platform_instance, launch_at: nil, expire_at: nil)
        end

        context 'when community assigned NO resource centers' do
          before(:each) do
            @rc.communities = []
            @rc.save!

            get :index
          end

          it_behaves_like '200 w name in body' do
            let(:names) { ['There are no files for your review at the moment.'] }
          end
        end

        context 'when community assigned ONE resource center' do
          before(:each) do
            @rc.communities = [@user.communities.first]
            @rc.save!
          end

          context 'when resource center assigned NO mediafiles' do
            before(:each) do
              @rc.mediafiles = []
              @rc.save!

              get :index
            end

            it_behaves_like '200 w name in body' do
              let(:names) { ['There are no files for your review at the moment.'] }
            end
          end

          # this test is flapping
          # sometimes it will persist the mediafile and it will show up
          # other times it will be saved, why is that?
          context 'when resource center assigned ONE mediafile' do
            before(:each) do
              @mediafile = FactoryBot.create(:mediafile, platform_instance: @platform_instance)
              @rc.mediafiles << @mediafile
              @rc.save!

              get :index
            end

            it_behaves_like '200 w name in body' do
              let(:names) { ["#{@mediafile.name}"] }
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the shared context

```
shared_context '200 w name in body' do
    it 'returns 200' do
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end

    it 'renders the view' do
      names.each do |name|
        expect(response.body).to include(name)
      end
    end
end
```

Edit: I learned of the bisect flag and ran it with this output

```
Bisect started using options: "spec/controllers/resource_center_controller_spec.rb"
Running suite to find failures... (7.39 seconds)
Starting bisect with 1 failing example and 5 non-failing examples.
Checking that failure(s) are order-dependent... failure appears to be order-dependent

Round 1: bisecting over non-failing examples 1-5 .. multiple culprits detected - splitting candidates (13.84 seconds)
Round 2: bisecting over non-failing examples 1-3 . ignoring examples 1-2 (6.95 seconds)
Round 3: bisecting over non-failing examples 4-5 . ignoring example 4 (6.75 seconds)
Bisect complete! Reduced necessary non-failing examples from 5 to 2 in 34.1 seconds.

The minimal reproduction command is:
  rspec ./spec/controllers/resource_center_controller_spec.rb[1:1:1:1:2:1:1:1,1:1:1:1:2:2:1:1,1:1:1:1:2:2:1:2]
```

Edit: here is the factory for mediafile

```
FactoryBot.define do
  # pi = PlatformInstance.select
  factory :mediafile do
    name { Faker::Simpsons.character }
    platform_instance_uuid { PlatformInstance.first.uuid } # stick to platforminstance.first for now
    platform_instance { PlatformInstance.first }           # had tried to use a variable, but was
                                                           # not working
    description { Faker::Simpsons.quote }
    document { File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/fixtures/mediafiles/document_01.pdf") }
    image { File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/fixtures/mediafiles/image_01.jpg") }

    # review_with_mediafiles will create mediafile data after the review has been created
    factory :mediafile_with_review do
      after(:create) do |mediafile, evaluator|
        create(:review, mediafile: mediafile)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the factory for resource center

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :resource_center do
    title { Faker::Company.catch_phrase }
    description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(10) }
    launch_at { Time.now }
    expire_at { Time.now + 1.week }
    platform_instance_uuid { PlatformInstance.first.uuid } # stick to PlatformInstance.first for now
    platform_instance { PlatformInstance.first }           # had tried to use a variable, but was
                                                           # not working
    status { [:testing, :live].sample }

    # review_with_mediafiles will create mediafile data after the review has been created
    # this factory inherits everything from the factory it is nested under
    factory :resource_center_with_mediafiles do
      after(:create) do |resource_center, evaluator|
        create(:mediafile, resource_centers: [resource_center])
      end
    end

  end
end
```

The controller method itself is fairly simple

```
def index
  @resource_centers = current_user.resource_centers.within_dates
end
```

current_user variable is assigned in the application controller which I don't think is super necessary to include here. The view is also fairly simple and can be seen below

```
-content_for :breadcrumbs do
  =render 'layouts/shared/breadcrumbs', breadcrumbs: [link_to('Home', user_root_path), 'Resource Center']

  -files_present = false
  -@resource_centers.each do |resource_center|
    -if resource_center.mediafiles.present?
      -files_present = true

      %h3.color-primary= resource_center.title.html_safe
      =resource_center.description.html_safe

      .space-above-2
        -resource_center.mediafiles.sort.each do |mediafile|
          =render 'resource_center/mediafile_item', resource_center: resource_center, mediafile: mediafile

  -if !files_present
    %h4 There are no files for your review at the moment.
```

Here is the partial rendered in the above view.

```
.index-list
  .index-item.large-avatar
    .item-avatar
      =link_to resource_center_mediafile_view_path(resource_center, mediafile) do
        = image_tag mediafile.image.url

    .item-content
      .item-header= mediafile.name

      .item-attribute-list
        %span.item-attribute
          -if mediafile.duration.present?
            %strong DURATION:
            =pluralize(mediafile.duration, "minute")
          -if mediafile.document.size.to_i > 0
            %strong SIZE:
            =number_to_human_size(mediafile.document.size)

    .item-actions
      -if resource_center.downloadable
        =link_to 'Download', mediafile.download_url, class: 'mui-button default', target: '_blank'
      =link_to 'View', resource_center_mediafile_view_path(resource_center, mediafile), class: 'mui-button'
```

Here is the spec_helper file:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    #only modify the request when testing controllers
    if described_class <= ApplicationController
      request.host = 'localhost:3000'
    end
  end

  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  # config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Please let me know if there is other information that would be helpful. I think this is something wrong with my test suite, particularly the before(:each) blocks, but my experimentation has not given me any insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I did not read the whole code you posted, so I won't give you the answer what causes this flakiness (or flappines as you call it) but I'll give you a method to find it yourself. ([fish vs. fishing rod thing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) kinda thing)

Using bisect is great, and since it says that the issue is order dependent it's fairly easy to continue.

You can now set a breakpoint in the failing `it` and investigate why the results are different than expected. Most probably there's some leftover `junk` in the DB left from some other spec.

When you pinpoint the reason for the failing spec, you can run command:

```
rspec  --format doc \ 
./spec/controllers/resource_center_controller_spec.rb[1:1:1:1:2:1:1:1,1:1:1:1:2:2:1:1,1:1:1:1:2:2:1:2]
```

This will tell you in what order the tests are run (since `[1:1:1:1:2:1:1:1,1:1:1:1:2:2:1:1,1:1:1:1:2:2:1:2]` is not very human friendly)
and you can look for the spec that leaves the "state unclean" (mentioned DB junk, but could be something else)

When you pin-point the offender you can add some crude fix (like `Model.destroy_all` after it, to confirm that it's The Reason).

Please note that this is not the proper fix yet.

After you confirm that this is true - you're ready to search for a solution. This can be using DBCleaner for your specs, or fixing some cache code that is misbehaving or something completely different (feel free to ask another question when you have the answers)

One extra note: in many projects order of the specs will be randomized. In such case `bisecting` will fail unless you know the `--seed` under which the specs fail.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to track down all the issues and things are working now. Putting this in my notes for future debugging.

Comment: Happy to help. What was wrong? Junk in DB or something else?

Comment: There were a few ordering issues, but the big issue was with a factory of all things. There was a field on the model we were testing that had an effect on the controller logic, but because we almost never use that particular field I had forgotten to assign it explicitly and the factory was assigning the value randomly. Not a fun time, but I learned a considerable amount about rspec so it wasn't a total loss :D

Comment: Oh yeah, after you fix it it seems obvious but it's because the investigation is learning. Do you mind If I updated your question title to something like `How to proceed with flaky specs after successfull bisect`? I think it would fit the answer better and maybe would help others find it.

Comment: Yeah go for it.